# how and when to use count(*),mention any cases,

Tags: mysql

i have tried count(*) with employees table in oracle(hr schema) then it returned number of employees.

what does count(*) in this query represent?

```
select 
    city, count(*)
from
    departments d
        join
    locations l ON (d.location_id = l.location_id)
group by city;
```

On submission i have got the answer but could not figure out what it returned.

Comment: Show us your code, please

Comment: It will select the city and its count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count(*)` returns the total number of rows returned by the query. 
but `count(*)` is an aggregate function. suppose returned city count is 2 then 2 is returned as an output to `count(*)`.

you could have searched using `count(city)`, it would also work.

I don't think there would be any confusion any more, if any please feel free to ask your concern.